# Dst tensor is not initialized. Even with small batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow

There are many, many questions about this on SO. The answers to all of them appear to be rather straight forward, pointing out it's almost certainly a memory error and that reducing the batch size should work.

In my case something else appears to be going on (or I am having a serious misunderstanding of how this work).

I have a large set of stimuli, like so:

```
train_x.shape # returns (2352, 131072, 2), amount 2.3k stimuli of size 131072x2
test_y.shape  # returns (2352,)
```

Of course, we can imagine that this might be too much. Indeed, creating a simple model and not setting any batch size returns in the `InternalError`.

```
model = Sequential([
    Flatten(input_shape=(131072, 2)), 
    Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu), 
    Dense(50, activation=tf.nn.relu), 
    Dense(1), 
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=5)
```

This returns the following error:

```
InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.
```

The logical thing to do is reduce the bath size. However, setting any value from 1 to 2000 simple returns the same error. This appears to imply that I don't have enough memory remaining to load a single stimuli. However..

#### Not just a memory error

If I manually cut up my dataset like so:

```
# Take first 20 stimuli
smaller_train_x = train_x[0:20,::] # shape is (20, 131072, 2)
smaller_trian_y = test_y[0:20]     # shape is (20, )
```

If I try to fit the model to this smaller dataset, it works and does not return an error.

```
model.fit(smaller_train_x, smaller_trian_y, epochs=5)
```

Thus, setting a `batch_size` of a single stimuli, I get a memory error. However, running on a manual cut of my dataset of 20 stimuli works fine.

### In short, the problem:

As I understand it

```
# Load in one stimuli at a time
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=5, batch_size=1)
```

should use ~20 times less memory then

```
# Load in 20 stimuli at a time
model.fit(smaller_train_x, smaller_trian_y, epochs=5)
```

How then does the first return an memory error?

I'm running this on a jupyer notebook with python version 3.8 and tensorFlow version 2.10.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the following experiments, size of train samples passed to `model.fit(...)` also matters along with the `batch_size`.

> **train_x:** *Peak GPU memory increased with batch_size but not linearly*

```
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=1, batch_size=10, callbacks= [MemoryPrintingCallback()])
#GPU memory details [current: 2.7969 gb, peak: 3.0 gb]

model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=1, batch_size=100, callbacks= [MemoryPrintingCallback()])
#GPU memory details [current: 2.7969 gb, peak: 3.0 gb]

model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=1, batch_size=1000, callbacks= [MemoryPrintingCallback()])
#GPU memory details [current: 2.7969 gb, peak: 4.0 gb]
```

> **smaller_train_x:** *Peak GPU lower than previous case for same batch size*

```
model.fit(smaller_train_x, smaller_trian_y, epochs=1, batch_size=10, callbacks= [MemoryPrintingCallback()])
#GPU memory details [current: 0.5 gb, peak: 0.6348 gb]
```

> **Converting train_x to tfrecords** *seems optimal, and linear increase in GPU memory*

```
dataset = dataset.batch(10)
model.fit(dataset, epochs=1,callbacks= [MemoryPrintingCallback()])
#GPU memory details [current: 0.5 gb, peak: 0.6348 gb]

dataset = dataset.batch(100)
model.fit(dataset, epochs=1,callbacks= [MemoryPrintingCallback()])
#GPU memory details [current: 0.5 gb, peak: 0.7228 gb]

dataset = dataset.batch(1000)
model.fit(dataset, epochs=1,callbacks= [MemoryPrintingCallback()])
#GPU memory details [current: 0.5 gb, peak: 1.6026 gb]
```

*`MemoryPrintingCallback()`: [How to print the maximum memory used during Keras's model.fit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70763324/how-to-print-the-maximum-memory-used-during-kerass-model-fit)*

*`numpy-to-tfrecords`: [Numpy to TFrecords: Is there a more simple way to handle batch inputs from tfrecords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427637/numpy-to-tfrecords-is-there-a-more-simple-way-to-handle-batch-inputs-from-tfrec/45428167#45428167)*